# How does php script handle two PHPSESSIDs?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

How does php script handle session vars if it gets two cookies with PHPSESSIDs ?
Does it populates $_SESSION with vars from first PHPSESSID or from last one ? Or just merges them ?

Comment: Try `<?php echo SID; ?>` and compare the echoed string with the cookie values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_COOKIE is an associative array, and the session cookie value would be parsed to that, so the last one wins. However, since browsers update the cookie when a "Set-Cookie" header is sent from the server, the only read reason for this is probably client-side tampering.

Comment: "Cookie" header is sent by browsers. Servers send "Set-Cookie" header.

Comment: @binaryLV's: you are indeed very right. Updated as per comment.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one active session. And it’s the first session ID that has been found in either `$_COOKIE`, `$_GET` or `$_POST` that’s name matches the current [*session.name*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) value.

Comment: Wouldn't it be whichever one was written last? I mean, if the browser received a cookie with the same name as an existing one, it would just overwrite it, right? It would never *send* two to the server, since I don't think it has the concept of "two identically named cookies", does it?

Comment: @AgentConundrum: There could be multiple cookies with different scopes. I’m currently not sure how browsers would handle that situation. I guess they would prefer the most specific one.

Comment: It will send if one of them is for .domain.com and the other is for domain forum.domain.com - so opening forum.domain.com browser sends both of them